# Rest API post call with token & multipartform returns 401 error

Tags: c#, rest, multipartform-data

I try to build a post request that contains form data content (file) and url. the Url is built this way:
http://base-url/api/endpoint?name=modelTest
This call works perfectly fine in postman but it seems i can't reproduce it in C# code.

My model object passed as param looks like this :

```
modelRequest.Model = @"C:\Users\temp\myFile.txt";
```

Here is the problematic method:

```
public async Task<ModelResponse> CreateModel(Uri url, ModelRequest modelRequest, string token)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url)) 
    { 
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(); 
        multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(
            File.ReadAllBytes(modelRequest.Model)), 
            "model", 
            Path.GetFileName(modelRequest.Model));
        request.Content = multipartContent;
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output));
        ModelResponse returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelResponse>(output);
        return returnValue;     
    }
```

I have a 401 response. I even tried the generated code generated with Postman and I obtain the same issue.

The generated code by postman is the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://base-url/api/endpoint?name=modelTest");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {token}");
request.AddFile("model", @"C:\Users\temp\myFile.txt");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: 401 typically means, the authentication token cannot be verfied. Do you have control over the server and can you debug there?

Comment: 401 means unauthorized

Comment: Btw. its bad practice to create a new HttpClient for every request https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I do not have control over server. it's a third party server I call

Comment: In first paragraph of your question you write *"This call works perfectly fine in postman"* and in the last sentence your write *"I even tried the generated code generated with Postman and I obtain the same issue"* What is it now. Does the call work in postman or not?

Comment: I set the URL, select the file and pass the token in postman and it works. I tried to use the generated code and i have 401 error...

Comment: So you are telling us, that you have taken unchanged the C# code generated by postman, put it into a new project and it didn't work? That's quite hard to believe. Can you add this generated code to the question? (Don't forget to obfuscate the token!)

Comment: The code seems fine. I still find it hard to believe that the code generated by Postman won't work (have you tried others, like cURL or JS) if it works in Postman. But without knowing details about the API it's quite hard to help, other than just throwing random guesses into the dark

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

instead of this

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: i also did it and i have the same result

Comment: I checked the token and It's valid and the mail is an admin account. I tried another post call without formdata and it works

Comment: is it getting passed into  CreateModel or is it null?

Comment: token is not null ... it is passed as a method param, not in the model